# From sets of elements to distance matrix

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I have some sets of elements, $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_k\subset M=\big\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\big\}$.

If two elements, $a_i$ and $a_j$ appear in one set, say, $A_l$, they're supposed to be similar to each other.

 I want to obtain a reasonable $n\times{n}$ distance or dissimilarity matrix from this setting.

 **Explanation**

 By similarity I mean the following, if we see $a_i$ and $a_j$ in one set only once, they probably are not very similar. However, if we see they appear in the same set for many times, they're very similar.

 Therefore, the similarity matrix I would propose is

 $\Sigma_{l=1}^k{\textbf{1}_l{\textbf{1}_l}^T}$, where $\textbf{1}_l$ is the hot-encoding vector that supplies the belongings of $a_i$ in $A_l$. For example, if the $i$-th entry of $\textbf{1}_l$ is 1, it means that $a_i\in{A_l}$; otherwise, it's $0$.

Comment: Can you please explain what happens if $a_i$ and $a_j$ appear in one set, but not in another, or if the appear in all sets. How does this affect the "similarity"?

Comment: @cdalitz Sure. Sorry that I didn't make it clear. In general, if $a_i$ and $a_j$ appear in one set, it could be due to coincidences or something common in $a_i$ and $a_j$. So, we cannot infer that $a_i$ and $a_j$ is similar to each other just by observing them in one set. However, if $a_i$ and $a_j$ appears simultaneously in many sets, we can infer they're very similar to each other.

Comment: You don't supply any information to permit an answer.  From what kinds of information or data is this distance matrix supposed to be derived??

Comment: As the question has been closed by an over-zealous moderator, let me answer here in teh comments section: simply use the number of sets in which $a_i$ and $a_j$ cooccur as the similarity measure $s$. To transform the similarity into a distance, you can utilize that the maximum similarity value is $k$, so $k-s$ is the distance.

Comment: @cdalitz I agree with your approach. However, I think there could be other modifications but I'm not sure if it's reasonable or if there exists other better approach. In fact, if $a_i$ appears only 100 times and $a_j$ appears 101 times and we see $a_i$ and $a_j$ appear in one set for, say 95 times, they're probably very similar. However, if we see $a_k$ and $a_m$ appear in the same sets for 105 times but they each appear 5000 times, they probably are not that similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first idea was what cdalitz wrote who can now make this an answer again. After the reply of Yanqi Huang, an alternative would be the Jaccard similarity: Divide the number sets in which both $a_i$ and $a_j$ appear by the number of sets in which any one of $a_i$ and $a_j$ appears. This is between 0 and 1, so one minus this is a distance (it actually fulfills the triangle inequality).

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I was willing to upvote this one but my reputation is too low to do so. I'm willing to receive your answer but I'll be waiting for other solutions to come to see if better ones appear. :)

Comment: Yes, I think your comment really gives intuitions and your answer fits better. Do you mind giving me some advanced references on clustering?

Comment: You might also consider the *Rand index*, which divides by the total number, but if $k$ is large and cooccurrences are rare, this will make the similarity considerably smaller than with the Jaccard index.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Lewian and @cdalitz. This way is the same as the one proposed by @cdalitz.

 Let $\vec{w}_i=[w_1\textrm{ }w_2\textrm{ ... }w_k]$ s.t.
$$w_l=\begin{cases}1&\textrm{if }a_i\in{A_l}\\0&\textrm{if }a_i\notin{A_l}\end{cases}$$
I can calculate the distance, denoted by $\textrm{dist}(a_i, a_j)$ to be
$$\textrm{dist}(a_i, a_j)=||\vec{w}_i-\vec{w}_j||^2$$
**Explanation**

 We're essentially viewing each $a_i$ as a Bernoulli random variable. The $k\textrm{ }A_l$'s are essentially $k$ observations. Then each $a_i$ can be represented as a point in a $k$-dimensional space. The distance is calculated accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for answering my own questions. I'm willing to receive other solutions. Since it's an open-ended question, I think any new creative approach would be the best.

Comment: This is the so-called simple matching distance. It is better than Jaccard if joint non-occurrence is as informative as joint occurrence. The Jaccard distance in my answer is based on only joint occurrences, which I understood from your question and comment to cdalitz is what you wanted?

Comment: This is exactly the same distance that I suggested. Note that your values $\omega_i$ are only zero or one and thus the square in the Eucledean distance has no effect ($1^2=1$ and $0^2=0$).

Comment: @cdalitz Yes, I now understand. Thanks for pointing out another way of interpretation.